# Composite unique index & INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, composite, unique-index

My head is about to explode, I'm in need of the following scenario in which column `a` is a foreign key INDEX. Also, a UNIQUE index of (`a`,`c`) exists, and column `c` is either `null` or not

Here's my current table and indexes:

```
  id |  a  |  b  |  c
-----------------------
  1  |  19 |  99 | null
  2  |  19 | abc | string
  3  |  34 | 123 | string
  4  |  5  | xyz | string
  5  |  34 | y2k | null

PRIMARY   PRIMARY (id)
a_c_uq_ix UNIQUE  (a,c)
fk_a      INDEX   (a)
```

But when I try to INSERT say row 6, I try:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (5, 777, null)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b='777'
```

And I get this UPDATE instead:

```
  id |  a  |  b  |  c
-----------------------
  4  |  5  | 777 | string
```

I believe that's the gist of it, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show the actual `create table` statement.  Based on your description, I could only image this happening if there were a trigger setting the `NULL` value to `'string'`.

Comment: You may be onto something here, column c is a timestamp with default `null`, but I'm also specifying `null` in the insert statement to reinforce the INSERT. As far as triggers go I've never touched those settings so they would be the default which is no triggers I believe.

Comment: I think UNIQUE INDEXES don't work well with `null` values.